# Counting specific words in a sentence

Tags: python, vector, nltk

I am currently trying to solve this homework question.

My task is to implement a function that returns a vector of word counts in a given text. I am required to split the text into words then use `NLTK's` tokeniser to tokenise each sentence.

This is the code I have so far:

```
import nltk
import collections
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('gutenberg')
nltk.download('brown')

def word_counts(text, words):
"""Return a vector that represents the counts of specific words in the text
>>> word_counts("Here is sentence one. Here is sentence two.", ['Here', 'two', 'three'])
[2, 1, 0]
>>> emma = nltk.corpus.gutenberg.raw('austen-emma.txt')
>>> word_counts(emma, ['the', 'a'])
[4842, 3001]
"""

from nltk.tokenize import TweetTokenizer
text = nltk.sent_tokenize(text)
words = nltk.sent_tokenize(words)

wordList = []

for sen in text, words:
    for word in nltk.word_tokenize(sen):

        wordList.append(text, words).split(word)

counter = TweetTokenizer(wordList)
return counter
```

There are two doctests that should give the result of:
[2, 1, 0] and [4842, 3001]

This is the error message I am getting from my code
[image]

I've spent all day trying to tackle this and I feel I'm getting close but I don't know what I'm doing wrong, the script is giving me an error every time.

Any help will be very appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: So. We are supposed to copy your code (good you put that in) and execute it and see the error in our IDEs for ourself? Why? Why not: copy and paste
the error message verbatim ( word for word) into your question? Avoid using screenshots unless you 
need to convey layout errors. We can NOT copy and paste your image into our IDEs to fix your code.

Comment: btw. your indendation for your code is off - probably due to splitting it with your "And this is the ..." - the comment `""" ... """`should be indentent - same fro your written code - and you lack the "call" to your function to make this a real [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please add the error message and stacktrace to your code and fix the code so we can copy&paste it into our IDEs, execute it and get the same error as you do - as starting point for fixing it. Thanks.

Comment: I apologise for my editting with my question, I'm still new the posting things like this, I shall post the error message along with more thorough editted question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I would use nltk to get to the result your homework wants:

```
import nltk
import collections
from nltk.tokenize import TweetTokenizer
# nltk.download('punkt')
# nltk.download('gutenberg')
# nltk.download('brown')

def word_counts(text, words):
    """Return a vector that represents the counts of specific words in the text
    word_counts("Here is one. Here is two.", ['Here', 'two', 'three'])
    [2, 1, 0]
    emma = nltk.corpus.gutenberg.raw('austen-emma.txt')
    word_counts(emma, ['the', 'a'])
    [4842, 3001]
    """  

    textTok = nltk.word_tokenize(text) 
    counts =  nltk.FreqDist(textTok)   # this counts ALL word occurences

    return [counts[x] for x in words] # this returns what was counted for *words

r1 = word_counts("Here is one. Here is two.", ['Here', 'two', 'three'])
print(r1) #    [2, 1, 0]

emma = nltk.corpus.gutenberg.raw('austen-emma.txt')
r2 = word_counts(emma, ['the', 'a'])
print(r2) # [4842, 3001]
```

Your code does multiple things that look just wrong:

> ```
> for sen in text, words:
>     for word in nltk.word_tokenize(sen):
>
>         wordList.append(text, words).split(word)
> ```

- `sent_tokenize()` takes a string and returns a list of sentences from it - you store the results in 2 variables `text, words` and then you try to iterate over tuple of them? `words` is not a text with sentences to begin, this makes not much sense to me
- `wordList` is a list, if you use the `.append()` on it, `append()` returns `None`. `None`has no `.split()` function.

Comment: Well I editted my question and added an error message to my problem, I shall be more clear and careful in future postings. I'm still a noob at this